# Code does not output expected value; how to modify it to obtain the expected result?

Tags: java, math

In the following  java code, the expected value is 78 but it returns a value 59. What modifications do I need to do to get the expected result?

```
public class SampleOne {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        int ans=42+45-48-5-15+20*2;

        System.out.println(" Ans="+ans);    
    }
}
```

Comment: `int ans = 78;`

Comment: apply the DIMAS rule for mathematical calculations, it should return 59 only.

Comment: add parentheses to the addition bit; leaving the multiplication out of the parentheses

Comment: 59 is the correct answer to what you've written. What's the question?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summary your specific technical issue.

Comment: Duplicate of: [*What is the right precedence of the math expression*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4023673/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use braces for complex operations.

Also, you should remember BODMAS Rule:
Bracket Of Divide Multiply Addition Subtraction

```
int ans=(42+45-48-5-15+20)*2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). The multiplication operator (`*`) is executed before the addition (`+`) and subtraction (`-`) ones, producing the result of 59.

It seems as though you meant to execute the operators in the order they appear in order to get the result of 78. You can't change Java's operator precedence, but you could force it to execute the addition/subtraction sequence before multiplying it by 2 by surrounding that calculation with parenthesis:

```
int ans = (42+45-48-5-15+20)*2; 
// Here---^----------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

59 is receiving because Machines follow the following priority order

Division -> Multipication -> addition -> Substraction

checkout [java docs on operator precidence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

in order to get your expected out-come, you need to use parenthesis

> open bracket - (
>   and closed brackets -)

convert your expression into `ans=(42+45-48-5-15+20)*2;`

in order to receive your expected results.