# Why System.out.println(3+(4-3)/2); is printing 3 but not 2 in java but System.out.println(4/2) is printing 2 correctly

Tags: java, math, division

Why System.out.println(3+(4-3)/2); is printing 3 but not 2  in java  but System.out.println(4/2)  is printing 2 correctly.

```
    public class Sum {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(3 + (4 - 3) / 2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: To me, it looks more like OP is struggling with operator order and is surprised that the / is evaluated before the +.

Comment: It's because `(4 - 3) / 2 = 1 / 2 = 0`

Comment: Probably related but probably more advanced: [What is the right precedence of the math expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023673/what-is-the-right-precedence-of-the-math-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as in math also in Java multiplication and division have higher precedence than addition and subtraction. Therefore your expression is equivalent to the following:

```
    3 + ((4 - 3) / 2)
```

So let’s just take it step by step:

```
    3 + (4 - 3) / 2 = 3 + ((4 - 3) / 2)
                    = 3 + (1 / 2)
                    = 3 + 0
                    = 3
```

As others have said, division of integers in Java is unlike division in math since any remainder is discarded. In school we learned that 1 / 2 is 0 with a remainder of 1. In Java we just get the 0.

As an aside: To have the remainder, the 1, you may do `1 % 2` or `(4 - 3) % 2`. And if we want the result of the division to be 0.5, we need to divide floating point values, for example `1.0 / 2.0` or `(4.0 - 3.0) / 2.0`.

Historic perspective: The rules for calculation that I have applied here are by no means unique to Java. The precise rules have been taken over from C++ and C, which may have taken them from even older programming languages. And in practically all programming languages you will find pretty similar rules.

**Had you expected left to right evaluation** except for the brackets? Another pair of brackets can ensure that:

```
    System.out.println((3 + (4 - 3)) / 2);
```

Output is:

> 2

I understood from your question that this was the output you had expected.

It’s becoming hard to read with this many nested brackets, though, so prefer to assign the value to a variable first:

```
    int result = (3 + (4 - 3)) / 2;
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output is still the same, of course. You have probably already realized that the calculation now goes:

```
    (3 + (4 - 3)) / 2 = (3 + 1) / 2
                      = 4 / 2
                      = 2
```

**Link:** [Operator Precedence in Java](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)

Comment: @Gray That may help some; done.